# JLabel loses bold font style when serialized

Tags: java, serialization, fonts, jlabel

I have a program I'm coding with a save function which uses serialization to save the main object. However, I'm noticing that while the entire program serializes correctly, the JLabels change from bold to regular style font directly after being serialized. I created an SSCCE to illustrate what I'm experiencing, which I will post at the end of this. My question, though, is why does this happen? It seems like a random thing to go wrong with serializing. Is there a way I can avoid this style change in my JLabels upon serializing?

the SSCCEE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JLabelSerializingTest extends JFrame
{
    public JLabel theLabel = new JLabel("This is a JLabel with bold text.");
    {
        theLabel.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        theLabel.setFont(theLabel.getFont().deriveFont(1));
    }
    public JButton theButton = new JButton("Serialize the JLabel");
    {
        theButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        theButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("This is a test"));
                    o.writeObject(theLabel);
                    o.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public JLabelSerializingTest()
    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        add(theButton);
        add(theLabel);
        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new JLabelSerializingTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Just an update, I still haven't found any sort of answer. I don't know how to "bump" the thread, but this is an attempt to bring it back into the attention of the public.

Comment: This is not the answer you're looking for (hence it's a comment), but I generally try to *avoid* serializing GUI's. Instead I try to persist data, and then use that data to populate my GUI.

Comment: I definitely agree. I'd prefer to do that, it's just that in this particular program I have a lot of different data fields & a strict time period to finish coding it in so I'm ending up spending time adding functionality to the program over creating an algorithm to save the data within the main object & then read it back. Fortunately, serialization has worked almost perfectly (with the exception of this, obviously) as a quick coding workaround, and even losing the bold font style isn't a big deal. Some of the labels just look nicer in bold, I think.

Comment: Consider using something like [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) instead of serialisation